# Is it possible to compile a X86 program on a jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: ios, gcc, clang, cross-compiling, jailbreak

I have an iPad running iOS 13.5 and it is jailbroken.
I installed clang compiler and vim editor on the Cydia store, so I can write code with vim and compile the source code with clang. Both compilation and execution are successful.

Now I have an idea, I know there is a method called cross-compile, so is it possible to compile a C program on iPad that can run in macOS or Windows?

Comment: A novel setup..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly compile for macOS. All you need is the SDK with header files and library stubs, which you can either copy from Xcode, or grab from [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs).
You can either pass its folder to the compiler with `-isysroot`, or place/symlink it to `/usr/share/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` where the compiler will find it automatically.
Once you've done that, you can run:

```
clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin -o t t.c
```

Compiling for Linux or Windows would work in similar fashion with `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu` and `--target=x86_64-windows-msvc` respectively, but in addition to a suitable SDK will also require a custom linker. You could presumably build LLVM's [`lld`](https://lld.llvm.org/) for iOS and then pass `-fuse-ld=ld.lld` for Linux or `-fuse-ld=lld-link` for Windows, but I haven't been able to find this as precompiled binary for iOS.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I compile a helloworld with `clang --target=x86_64-apple-darwin -o test main.c -I /var/mobile/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ -L /var/mobile/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib`. But I got an error `zsh: killed     ./test` while running it on mac

Comment: Oh! It just a sign problem. macOS stop the program running for no signature. I fixed it with the codesign command.